# PHP : Getting link to image uploaded to directory

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am adding posts in database and against each post there  will be an image.  For example there is a product table and against each product I've its id, quanitity and price.

Now I store image like this in

```
if ( isset($_POST["uploadimg"]) ) {
    $file_name =$_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $file_type=$_FILES["image"]["type"];
    $file_size=$_FILES["image"]["size"];
    $tmp_name=$_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];

    if ( $file_name ) {
        if ( move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"images/$file_name") ) {
            // something here
        }
    }
}
```

fetch it like this

```
$folder = "images";
if ( is_dir($folder) ) {
    if ( $handle= opendir($folder) ) {
        while (($file=  readdir($handle))!=FALSE) {
            if($file==='.' || $file==='..')  continue;
            echo '<img src="images/'.$file.'" width="100" height="100" >';
        }
        closedir($handle); 
    }
}
```

Now product image goes to folder and details about this product go to db, using insert query.

My question is that how do i relate this image with its product details while fetching products?

I mean  how do i store reference to this  image so that I may know which image is for which product details.

Comment: You can store image name in database so that you can retrieve image name with select query and show image.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the path or the image name in the database.

You must have a new column in the product table like imgpath or something like this.

I'm not sure if this answers the question but I hope I could help you.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10791383)

Comment: @GAMITG I'm sorry. I know that i have no enough reputation to write a comment and I also know what reputation points are.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the simple way as below:

While saving the product in the database table you should rename image name with reference of `"product id"` and save in the field which is `"image_path"` and see the below code.

```
if ( isset($_POST["uploadimg"]) ) {
    $file_name = $product_id . '_' . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $file_type = $_FILES["image"]["type"];
    $file_size = $_FILES["image"]["size"];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];

    if ( $file_name ) {
        if ( move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "images/$file_name") ) {
            // once image uploaded successfully update your product table with image_path field = $file_name
        }
    }
}
```

To fetch the image with product id here is the example how to get it.
write select query with product table and get `"image_path"` field value after that add your uploaded image path and concat both values and put in the `<img src="<?php echo $image_full_path; ?>">` it will be show in the product page.

Please let me know feel free if any issue persist.

Thanks

Comment: what code i wite here thats what i was asking              // once image uploaded successfully update your product table with image_path field = $file_name

Comment: update query to update the image_path field in the db with renamed image name